# Use components as JProgressBar on java game

Tags: java, swing

Been building up a little game in java, already asked a few questions about the usage of JPanel in it, and used them to paint the graphics and the main part of the screens.

Now i have a little doubt about other components. My intention is to add on the corner a pair of bars to show health and mana of an entity (like in a rpg game), and wondered which was the best approach for it.
Thought about making a new JPnale with a pair of JProgressBar to set the ammount of it, but then i wondered if it would be better to paint it completely and fill a pair of rectangles.

I mean, doing a pair of new JProgressBar() for it, or a pair of g.fillRect() and then paint the ammounts.

I guess that easiest is to set the JProgress, as i can set values and text if i want, maybe, but not sure about it and if it would run smoother without overwhelming it with JComponents.

Also, if want to add buttons would be better the JButton, or paint a rectangle and check for containment of the mouse pointer with an event (I have this approach at some points where there is not KeyBinding). Should i change that?

Thank you beforehand :)

Comment: I am not sure, but I would think about implementing those bars in your graphics engine (the rectangles idea is not that bad).  If you work it well, I think the result will be far better

Comment: I mean, doing a pair of new JProgressBar() for it, or a pair of g.fillRect() and then paint the ammounts. - this is possible in Java7  and newer versions by using JLayer, creates painting illusion

Comment: Didn't know the JLayer feature of Java7 (using 6 to keep some compatibility). I've looked a bit about that and looks interesting, thank you for pointing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing an answer because i haven't got enough reputation to comment :(

I think is better if you paint it in your graphics engine. Use `Rectangles` is of course a better idea than use a new `JPanel` with `JProgressBar`.

But i think that it's even better if you use `Images` to build your own `Progress Bar`.
You can create them or find them on internet.

For example you can take an `Image` for the `Progress Bar` `Background`, and another `Image` for the `Foreground` (the part that will fill the `Bar`). Then you can set their `X` and `Y` position and then just change the `Foreground Width` in relation with the entity health to fill or empty the `Progress Bar`.

Comment: I'm going to follow that advice and manipulate the images to achieve the effect, thank you for the tip :)